# ViewPoint not preserved during Graphics3D Export

Tags: graphics3d, export

When I define a variable `myfig` as a `Graphics3D` object rendered with a specified `ViewPoint`, the graphic is properly rendered onscreen, but in some cases when `Exported` (`Export[...myfile.eps, myfig, "EPS"]`) the .eps image shows the graphic from another (default) `ViewPoint`.  How can one force the `ViewPoint` to be preserved during `Export`?

Comment: Often things like this can be done my explicitly passing the argument to `Export` (sometimes needing to be first converted to a string). Does that work?

Comment: I don't quite understand your recommendation.  I define `myfig = Graphics3D...]`, then on the next line `Export[..., myfig, "EPS"]`.  Is there some trick with `$DisplayFunction` I'm missing?

Comment: Hmm actually I'm not able to reproduce your issue just with regular `Export`. Can you provide an example that fails for you?

Comment: Alas, the code is long and complicated.  I think I'm revealing everything necessary in my posting.  Thanks for considering this.  My workaround (when it happens) is to hand copy the display cell (in proper ViewPoint), then define a new variable and paste the image as its referent, and then Export that new variable.  That works.

Comment: What were you trying instead? Were you exporting the cell? I only imagined exporting a `Graphics3D` expression

Comment: I was exporting a Graphics3D expression.  When that (inexplicably) lost the ViewPoint, I hand copy the image, assign it a name, and export that.

Comment: I've seen the same. The manually adjusted view of 3D image keeps as is when you run this cell again and again. So MMa have it in the FronEnd (and the right-click "Save Image as" saves the current view). But it resets to default if you try export the featured graphics by the associated name.
The way to Export is to set the ViewPoint directly, taking it from the rendered result

Comment: @Rom:  Thanks.  I *knew* I wasn't alone in this problem!  Whey you say "set the `ViewPoint` directly, taking it from the rendered result," what exactly do you mean.  When I render the figure in the first place, I specify a `ViewPoint` explicitly.  How do I "tak[e] it from the rendered result"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current ViewPoint of the 3D-graphics drawn in FrontEnd can be easily obtained by following (sorry, I put it as image but it is more clear):

[image]

*{ViewPoint -> {0.772292, 1.91213, 2.68278}}*

You will have always the new VP if you move somehow the graphics and after evaluate the cell again.

Therefore, you can `Export` your `Graphics3D` with manually adjusted `ViewPoint` just adding the defined VP into the definition of your Graphics3D explicitly.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks so much.  (I should have known that.) (accept $\checkmark$)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, Actually I don't know is it feature or bug of modern versions of MMa. The old versions have the ViewPoint selector in top menu but the new don't.